# How do you deal with the equations numbering in Pages?

Tags: macos, pages, formatting

How can I number equations in Pages following standard form:

[image]

P.S. No, I don't want to use MS Word... I usually write in LaTeX, however, some documents/papers cannot be given for a review in `.tex` format.

Comment: What do you mean by "equations numbering"?

Comment: Are you asking about some sort of automatic numbering? Or do you want to reference equations in the text? Are you using the built in LaTeX equation editor?

Comment: Pages supports some LaTeX, and so you can try that - [About LaTeX and MathML support in Pages, Numbers, Keynote, and iBooks Author](https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT202501). If that doesn't help, then please tell us specifically, and with details, what you would like to do.

Comment: @grg Automatic numbering would be nice, however, Pages does not offer such option to my knowledge. I just want to align the numbering on the right side and make references to it. Some of it can be done, but I am sorry of hoping that I may have missed some tricks. And yes, I am. using the built in LaTeX / MathML editor.

Comment: @sfxedit I looked here in the past, however I did not find any satisfying answer. I also wrote feedback about it to Apple, however, we all know that this is more of a formality than a real hope :).

Comment: @JoshE. Due to the limited support of LaTex on Pages, you may have to turn to other apps like [Compositor](https://compositorapp.com/) or [other opensource and free LaTex editors](https://medevel.com/10-latex-tex-editors-macos/).

Comment: I assume you can't hand in PDFs for review then. Would using tables in Pages work to get close to the formatting you need (one colum for the formula, one for the numbering)?

Comment: @nohillside That was actually the closest I got, however, inserting equations in the tables and especially the synergy of the table positioning alongside the text was poor - I refer to the case when I had to put more text before (let's say) 8 or 10 equations written in the table.

Comment: @sfxedit Thanks for the suggestion, I think I heard about this one, a long time ago I maybe even tried it. The thing is that in the end, I would need to convert the text in the MS Word, which Pages handles very flawlessly to my surprise.

Comment: *"I just want to align the numbering on the right side and make references to it."* I've answered that before, so I've linked this question to that one.

Comment: @grg By the way, do you have any similar tricks on how to position tables and figures such that when a lot of text is put before, the table/figure would move with the original text?